# How can I use GNU-utils to filter text like this?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

OK, so basically I am trying to use `GNU_Utils` to filter texts from a single code file.

The code is like this:

```
 // space line
 <fun1>    // no space
   ins1;    // two space before 
   ins2;
   ins3;

 <fun2>   // no space
   ins4;
   ins5;
 ....

 <fun3>
 .....
```

Currently I have a black list of functions, which should be filtered out in the above text.

```
blacklist : func2
```

So my question is:

how can I use tools from `GNU-Utils` to process the above text and filter out functions in the "blacklist"..? (In the above case, I should remove the `func2` with its body)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove `fun2`:

```
awk '/^fun2/ {a=0;next} /^[a-z]/ {a=1} a'
```

Suppose we have an input file, `infile`, which looks like:

```
$ cat infile

fun1
  ins1;
  ins2;
  ins3;

fun2
  ins4;
  ins5;

fun3
  ins6;
```

Then, using the above:

```
$ awk '/^fun2/ {a=0;next} /^[a-z]/ {a=1} a' infile
fun1
  ins1;
  ins2;
  ins3;

fun3
  ins6;
```

#### How it works

We want to remove blocks that begin with `fun2`.  So, whenever a line that begins `fun2` is encountered, the flag `a` is set to zero and the line is not printed.  No further line is printed until the flag is set to `1` which happens every time a block is encountered that starts with anything other than `fun2`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with groups of data, its better to treat it as an group.

```
awk '!/^fun2/' RS="" ORS="\n\n" file
fun1
  ins1;
  ins2;
  ins3;

fun3
  ins6;
```

Setting Record Selector to nothing makes one record for every group instead of one line.
Then do a test and tell you do not like a record that starts with `fun`
Setting the Output Record Selector to two new line preserves the blank line between records.

---

If there are no blank line between the group, you could with `gnu awk` use `fun` as separator:
(it will also preserve the empty lines)

```
awk '!/^2/' RS="fun" ORS="fun" file
fun1
  ins1;
  ins2;
  ins3;

fun3
  ins6;
```

This should work too, but its better to use quotes.

```
awk '!/^2/' RS=fun ORS=fun file
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but I have another question... What if the function name is not at the beginning of certain line..? For example, it is like `random_addr functionname` format..?

Comment: If the group of data is divided by an empty/blank line it will work fine.  You can use `RT` function to use pattern in `RS` if its in the same format but have different data.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^fun/h;G;/fun2/!P;d' file
```

Every new function header store in the hold space. Append the function header to each line and if the required header appears do not print it.

Now convert the `blacklist` into the sed script above:

```
# blacklist file (blfile) contains function headers separated by a space

sed 's/^blacklist : //;s/ /\\|/g;s|.*|/^fun/h;G;/&/!P;d|' blfile | sed -f - file
```